# Regular expression to include type of URL except one

Tags: regex

How do you write a regular expression to include all the URLs that contain:

```
/this/that/
```

Except:

```
/this/that/99-text
```

This is what I tried:

```
/this/that/
^www.domain.com//this/that/99-text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\/this\/that\/(?!99-text)
```

https://regex101.com/r/yK4zH1/1

It uses a **negative lookahead** to ensure it isn't followed by `99-text`.

If you want an *optional forward slash* after `/this/that`, you could do something like:

```
\/this\/that\/?(?!\/?99-text)
```

https://regex101.com/r/pN3cJ6/1

To take it an extra step, if it's valid to have something like `/this/that99-text`, you could do the following:

```
\/this\/that(?:\/(?!99-text)|(?!\/99-text))
```

https://regex101.com/r/yV8cO8/1

Comment: Thanks a lot, This seems like an easy question but I struggled a lot with it. The second proposal is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Use negative look-ahead:

```
$URI="/this/that/99-text";

if( preg_match_all("#/this/that(?!/99-text)#", $URI,$matches) )
{
  var_dump($matches);
}
else
{
 echo 'No matches found.';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried (?!99\-text)/this/that but it isn't working (it is including everything that contains /this/that/)